# how to retrieve records in sql when you pass in a certain day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to retrieve records for certain days .

```
 DateTime BETWEEN DATEADD(dd,-1* 30,GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
```

The above code gets all the records from todays date to 30 days back, but I only want the records thats on the 30th day and not all in between.How do I achieve this?

But its not always going to be 30 days, if i enter 5 days it must give me only the records for the 5th day etc

Comment: what you mean by 30 th day. is it day of month

Comment: No need of BETWEEN operator than. You can simply use Datetime = DATEADD(...). Also, you need to declare a variable as input as it can 5th or 30th day. With input variable you can pass the number of days back records to be retrieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return data for the date that is -30th day from today.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME 
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(),110), 
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), COLUMNNAME,110)) = -30
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

this is Returns Todays Date=`18`

```
DATEPART(Day,MyColumn)=30
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you care about time:

```
DateTime >= DATEADD(dd, -30, GETDATE()) and DateTime < DATEADD(dd, -29, GETDATE())
```

If you want a standard day definition:

```
DateTime >= DATEADD(dd, -30, cast(GETDATE() as date)) and DateTime < DATEADD(dd, -29, cast(GETDATE() as date))
```

Two notes.  First, I would discourage you from using `between` with dates and datetimes.  They often do not perform as expected when there is a time component.  Getting in the habit of using explicit comparisons (with `>=` and `<`) will likely prevent future problems.

Second, notice that the column `DateTime` is not part of any function.  All the "arithmetic" is on `getdate()`.  This keeps the expression sargable, so an index (if available) could be used.

Answer (score 0):

You do something like:

```
WHERE Cast(DateTime as DATE) = DATEADD(dd,-30,GETDATE())
```

but this isn't Sargable since for every row of your column "DateTime" will need to apply a transformation (Cast()).

Instead, it should be better to still use between, but only to select the data between 30 and 29 days ago:

```
WHERE DateTime BETWEEN DATEADD(dd,-30,GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(dd,-29,GETDATE())
```

Depending on if you want exclusivity, you might need to use less than/greater than instead of BETWEEN (which uses less than or equal to/greater than or equal to).